# Convert/Create JSON from 2 arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, arrays, json

I have a problem creating a JSON array in JavaScript. My source code looks like:

array1:

```
aOrderInformations[0]         = BestellNummer;
aOrderInformations[1]         = Lieferant;
aOrderInformations[2]         = Bestellgrund;
aOrderInformations[3]         = Besteller;
aOrderInformations[4]         = Mitarbeiter;
aOrderInformations[5]         = Standort;
aOrderInformations[6]         = Gesellschaft;
aOrderInformations[7]         = Bestelldatum;
aOrderInformations[8]         = Begruendung;
aOrderInformations[9]         = Lieferanschrift;
aOrderInformations[10]        = Rechnungsanschrift;

aOrderInformations = new Array(aOrderInformations);
```

array2 comes from server with ajax (here the PHP):

```
$sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
    FROM   $sTable
    WHERE BestellID = '".$bestellid."'
    ORDER BY $sIndexColumn DESC
";

$rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($rResult)) 
{ 
    $aPositions[] = $data; 
}  
echo json_encode( $aPositions );
```

array2 (here the Javascript):

```
success: function(data) {
    aPositions = data;
```

When I debug both array alone, it will shown in the correct syntax. But when I try to send it as follow to php it don´t combine the arrays and show only one array:

```
{
  "0": {
    "0": "292",
    "1": "1",
    "2": "Microsoft",
    "3": "Maus",
    "4": "33355520",
    "5": "MISCO Germany Inc.",
    "6": "510014",
    "7": "1",
    "8": "22.02",
    "9": "22.02",
    "PostenID": "292",
    "ProduktID": "1",
    "Hersteller": "Microsoft",
    "Beschreibung": "Maus",
    "Produktnummer": "33355520",
    "Lieferant": "MISCO Germany Inc.",
    "Artikelnummer": "510014",
    "Menge": "1",
    "PreisNettoEinzeln": "22.02",
    "PreisNettoGesamt": "22.02"
  }
}
```

The Code to send the combined array to php is the following:

```
var postData = $.extend({}, aOrderInformations, aPositions);
var postData = JSON.stringify(postData);
if(!ajaxload2) {
    alert(postData);
    ajaxload2 = true;   
    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        url : 'share/content/helper/writeorderdata.php',
        cache: false,
        dataType : 'json',
        data: {postData:postData},
        success: function() {
                        ajaxload2 = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Tip: SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is only useful if you're using a `LIMIT`. You're not, so it's pointless.

Comment: What do you see in your PHP?  What's your PHP code ?  Or is your question why your combined object is showing the JSON with keys that are both numbers and words?  Extend will end up clobbering itself if your two items have common keys . . .

Comment: You could send both arrays seperately in your ajax call (the `data` section) - that would at least narrow down where your problem is